# Italic or not in equations?

Tags: math-mode, equations, typography, italic

I have written two equations for the report of my Master thesis:

```
$NLL_{k} = - \sum_{j=1}^n \ln(pdf(PD_{k}^{i},skill_{i}^{j}))$

$person_{k}(interest) = \dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{p=1}^n \dfrac{person_{k}(task_{p})}{\alpha_{k}^{i}}$
```

[image]

[image]

In math mode everything is italic (except `\ln`). Is this ok or how should this be correctly formated?

Second, let's say I would like to use part of the equation in text. For example, I would like to write "It is visible that `$person_{k}$` has very high interest.". Should `$person_{k}$` in this case be in italic?

Comment: For such words I would use `\text{person}` etc, not in italic font. The reason why `\ln` is set upright is its definition as `\DeclareMathOperator`

Comment: never use the default math italic font for multi-letter words it is designed to make consecutive letters _not_ look like a word, but as a product of variables. Even if you want the word in italic use `\mathit{person}` or `\mathrm{person}` for upright. (compare $difficult$ and $\mathit{difficult}$`

Comment: Whatever you choose, define a symbolic and semantic command, which will make absolutely easy to change the definition later. For instance `\var` or `\mvar` (math variable) could look good, but you can choose the name you want.

Answer (score 4):

Opinion based answer: For variables that have human readable names or are `acronyms` (somehow), I would prefer `\text` or a `\DeclareMathOperator` approach (or `\mathit` and `\mathrm`, depending on personal taste)

If the symbols are used more than once, markup macros are a better way

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\DeclareMathOperator{\pdf}{pdf}

\begin{document}

Original version


$NLL_{k} = - \sum_{j=1}^n \ln(pdf(PD_{k}^{i},skill_{i}^{j}))$

$person_{k}(interest) = \dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{p=1}^n \dfrac{person_{k}(task_{p})}{\alpha_{k}^{i}}$

With \verb!\text!: 

\begin{equation}
  \text{NLL}_{k} = - \sum_{j=1}^n \ln(\pdf(\text{PD}_{k}^{i},\text{skill}_{i}^{j}))
\end{equation}

$\text{person}_{k}(\text{interest}) = \dfrac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{p=1}^n \dfrac{\text{person}_{k}(\text{task}_{p})}{\alpha_{k}^{i}}$


With \verb!\mathit!: 

\begin{equation}
  \mathit{NLL}_{k} = - \sum_{j=1}^n \ln(\pdf(\mathit{PD}_{k}^{i},\mathit{skill}_{i}^{j}))
\end{equation}

$\mathit{person}_{k}(\mathit{interest}) = \dfrac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{p=1}^n \dfrac{\mathit{person}_{k}(\mathit{task}_{p})}{\alpha_{k}^{i}}$


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @machinery: Some purists say: yes, but I personally find italics math style for `variable` names awful

Comment: Alright, but what about "NLL" for negative log-lieklihood or "AIC" for the Akaike information criterion? Are these also acronyms?

Comment: @machinery - "NLL" and "AIC" pretty much fit the very definition of acronym, don't they?

Comment: @machinery $NLL$ is the markup for N times N times L, so you want `\mathrm{NLL}` or `\mathit{NLL}` or, perhaps `\text{NLL}` according to taste. (`\text` picks up the surrounding text font which may or may not be what you want)

Comment: @Mico: Very true, yes! Perhaps, a combination with `acronym` or `glossaries` would be quite fancy!

Comment: But with \mathit it looks very similar to the original, i.e. italic.

Comment: @machinery: The spacing (kerning!) is better for `\mathit` than usual math italic mode

Comment: @machinery The problem with `\text` is that it takes the surrounding style, so if you are in a theorem with italics, those words would be in italic. Above all, *define* `\var` and use `\var{person}` and then you can change definition after if you find that it doesn't work as expected. So, if you want upright, use `\newcommand*\var{\mathrm}` or with `\newcommand*\var{\textnormal}`, and if you want italics, use `\newcommand*\var{\mathit}` or `\newcommand*\var[1]{\textnormal{\textit{#1}}}`.

Comment: @Manuel That sounds interesting. How should I define var? Should I set `\newcommand*\var{\mathrm}` in the preamble?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Would it be possible that you add the idea from Manuel to your solution? This seem very interesting.

Comment: @machinery Yes, in the preamble, that way you never have to touch the code of the document if you want to change some behaviour. Look at the question that this one has been marked as duplicate of. There he defines `\mvar` exactly as I had suggested. Bur if you want upright you can do `\newcommand*\var{\mathrm}` and if something doesn't go as expected, have in mind that may be `\textnormal` might solve it, but from the start I would rely only on `\mathrm`.

Comment: you might explain briefly the difference between a "word" and an "operator".  i've seen `\DeclareMathOperator` misused when `\text` (or `\textrm` or `\textit`) was what was really needed.